# Is it possible assigning an separate LAN IP to service/daemon?

Tags: networking, ip

I'm using `pfsense` for prioritizing traffic around LAN. It works well for specified port, IP, network, but I'm having a problem with torrent (transmission bittorrent) outbound connections. The outbound connections are random and no filter can be specified to slow them down if needed.

So I was thinking was it possible to specify a virtual IP just for the transmission daemon so I could use separate rules just for that IP?

The example would be:

```
Machine IP:          192.168.0.1
Transmission Daemon: 192.168.0.2
```

If not, what are the other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/999578) has similar question consisting torrent and pfsense.

I think it is possible to set outbound ports in utorrent. Look for net.outbound_port and net.outbound_max_port.

For linux qBittorrent is equivalent to utorrent.

To use another IP address for particular service. Set a virtual IP and put rule in iptables to SNAT packets originating from particular port or range of ports.

Comment: I saw that link when I was searching for the solution. I would prefer to continue using transmission. So you're saying that it is possible to set some kind of virtual ip to a service/daemon? If so, how?

Comment: I do not know is it possible to set outbound port range in transmission and if yes, how. Suppose it is possible($PORTSTART-$PORTEND) then you can add one more virtual ip($IP2) to the system and then create iptables rule such as *iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --source-port $PORTSTART:$PORTEND -j SNAT --to-source $IP*  (replace udp if using udp ports), so that your firewall will get originationg ip as IP2.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible in transmission to set outbound range of ports, although the feature has been requested a while ago. Yes, I can change the torrent that has such option, however I'm interested if this is possible in general.

Comment: Yes it is possible like I said above.

Comment: There is no option in settings.json in transmission where you can specify the range of outbound connections. Yes, you can set outbound connections via IP tables, but transmission will use everything from 1-65535.

Comment: ok sorry when you said *in general*, I thought you are asking if it is possible in general for any service.

Answer (score 1):

To use an ad-hoc ip-address to monitor/limit a service is usually a good technique but **the service has to support it**.

You are lucky, TrasmissionBT supports it :-)

Check [this page](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/EditConfigFiles) of transmission wiki. Look for `bind-address-ipv4` and `bind-address-ipv6` options.

---

It seems that I was wrong on this. I found a good solution for you in this superuser question: [How to use different network interfaces for different processes?](https://superuser.com/questions/241178/how-to-use-different-network-interfaces-for-different-processes)

Look ad [akira](https://superuser.com/users/10674/akira) solution. He proposes to use an ad-hoc library to intercept `bind` system call.

Comment: That only works for inbound connections which are not a problem, I can easily control traffic for a specific port, but not for a random outbound port.